# Rotate around unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to rotate an object around another one.
Here is the script I'm using:

```
public GameObject objectToRotate;

private bool rotating;

private IEnumerator Rotate(Vector3 angles, float duration)
{
    rotating = true;
    Quaternion startRotation = objectToRotate.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(angles) * startRotation;
    for (float t = 0; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        objectToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, endRotation, t / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
    objectToRotate.transform.rotation = endRotation;
    rotating = false;
}

public void StartRotation()
{
    if (!rotating)
        StartCoroutine(Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), 0.5f));
}
```

and there I have a script to rotate around an object around another one:

```
    public Button rotateLeftToRight, rotateRightToLeft;

public GameObject levelInvarte, character;
```

public void LeftToRight()
{
levelInvarte.transform.RotateAround(character.transform.position, Vector3.back, 90);

```
}

public void RightToLeft()
{
    levelInvarte.transform.RotateAround(character.transform.position, Vector3.back, -90);
}
```

What I should edit for the first code to rotate like in the second one(around another object, in the first it just rotate the object not around something)?

Comment: To rotate around an object you use the center of the object you want to rotate around with a radius.

Comment: i'll be thankful if you can tell me how to achieve that...:)

Comment: Use StartCoroutine(Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), 0.5f));  where 0,0 is the x,y location of center of object you are rotating around and 0.5f is the radius of the rotation.

Comment: Look.. check out the second script. That's what i want to achieve. I want to rotate object one around object two. But how can i implement that in script no. 1?

Comment: Add parameters to the method so you can pass the object, the position and the radius.

Comment: Srry but i highly don't understand. I apologize. Can you edit the code or just simply paste what you wanna say here? Thanks in advance. @jdweng

Comment: You just have piece of code.  I can't fix what is posted.